# Query really slow when changing join field

Tags: sql-server, performance

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I noticed an enormous difference in performance when running these two almost identical queries.

Fast query (takes less than a second):

```
SELECT Season.Description, sum( Sales.Value ) AS Value
FROM Seasons, Sales
WHERE Sales.Property05=Seasons.Season
GROUP BY Seasons.Description
```

Slow query (takes around 5 minutes):

```
SELECT Season.Description, sum( Sales.Value ) AS Value
FROM Seasons, Sales
WHERE Sales.Property04=Seasons.Season
GROUP BY Seasons.Description
```

The only difference is that the tables SALES and SEASONS are joined on Property05 in the fast query and Property04 in the slow one.

Neither of the two property fields are in a key nor in an index so I really don't understand why the execution plan and the performances are so different between the two queries.

Can somebody enlighten me?

EDIT: The query is automatically generated by a Business Intelligence program, so I have no power there. I would have normally used the JOIN ON sintax, although I don't know if that makes a difference.

Slow query plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkcBc7gXZ

Fast query plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJQ95mgXb

Note that the query above were simplified to the essential part. The query plans are more detailed.

Comment: You should include the create table statements and query plan

Comment: There might be an index on Property05. You should really be using the ON statement in your query. Like INNER JOIN Sales ON Sales.Property05 = Seasons.Season. Not using the Inner Join and ON is like the old Oracle format.

Comment: Wild guess: the statistics for `Sales.Property05` and `Sales.Property04` aren't remotely the same (possibly because the *data* isn't remotely the same), causing different estimates in the join predicate and hence a different join operator. I wouldn't need a wild guess if you [shared the query plans](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan), though.

Comment: You really should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Maybe your first query digests fewer rows (not the same as resulted rows)